# AWS SAM AccessDeniedException on a Lambda that uses the AWS SDK

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-sam

I have an AWS Lambda function in Node.js that uses the SDK method [`listVersionsByFunction`](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Lambda.html#listVersionsByFunction-property).

It's created from this AWS SAM template:

```
AWSTemplateFormatVersion: '2010-09-09'
Transform: AWS::Serverless-2016-10-31
Globals:
  Function:
    Timeout: 3
Resources:
  special:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      FunctionName: 'my-project-special'
      CodeUri: ./handlers
      Handler: special.handler
      Runtime: nodejs10.x
  getLatest:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      CodeUri: ./handlers
      Handler: getLatest.handler
      Runtime: nodejs10.x
      Events:
        getLatest:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            Path: /latest/
            Method: get
```

and the handler calls the SDK like this:

```js
const result = await lambda.listVersionsByFunction({
    FunctionName: 'my-project-special',
}).promise();
```

After deploying and making a request, there's an `AccessDeniedException` error:

> User: arn:aws:sts::999999999:assumed-role/my-project-getLatest-ADFADSFASD/my-project-getLatest-HJLKHLKJKJ is not authorized to perform: lambda:ListVersionsByFunction on resource: arn:aws:lambda:us-east-2:999999999:function:my-project-special

How can I allow this access by means of the AWS SAM template?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is indicating that your Lambda does not have permission to perform `ListVersionsByFunction`operation on other resources (another Lambda).

What you have to do is to create a custom policy and add it to your `template`.

```
getLatest:
    Type: AWS::Serverless::Function
    Properties:
      CodeUri: ./handlers
      Handler: getLatest.handler
      Runtime: nodejs10.x
      Policies:
         - Version: '2012-10-17'
           Statement:
             - Effect: Allow
               Action:
                 - lambda:ListVersionsByFunction
               Resource: '*'
      Events:
        getLatest:
          Type: Api
          Properties:
            Path: /latest/
            Method: get
```

[See reference](https://github.com/awslabs/serverless-application-model/blob/master/versions/2016-10-31.md)

Or you can also add this policy as `inline policy` in **IAM Management Console**, under Roles select your function `getLatest` and add the policy. see snapshot.

[image]
Hope it helps

Comment: Perfect answer for this question!